# Transfer PHP session to flash

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3

we developed an internet application for company purposes a while back (company and friends, to be precise :]) and now we're trying transfer PHP session to loaded Flash, so flash can identify itself as being loaded with user profile (stored in MySQL, accessed only by PHP so far) when communicating with server (either FMS or Wowza)

Can you advise any safe way to put some code (probably not credentials, but maybe some temporary hash stored in db?) from PHP to code that includes flash, so I can later use it in my flash application when communicating with DB?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to `transfer` the session?  Why not just use Flash as the front-end gateway, and have it talk to a php server somewhere (communicating via AMF)?  That way you can do all your security measures in PHP, and not require the flash app to talk directly to the database (which in most worlds would be considered bad since you'd need to provide credentials for it to do it...  Basically handing access to your database server to potential malevolent people)...

Comment: @ircmaxell : agree, was going to write that..

Comment: Not really transfered, that might be my poor english. I need to expressly tie a running instance of flash to a user account and also check if user is logged in and indentifies as himself before I start to send any data to flash (running local copies...)

Comment: also, talking to PHP isn't 100% ok, since I need to send events to client's flash based on actions of other users and I can't do so through PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP default session is based on COOKIES.

That said you just need to pass the [`session_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) to Flash on load as a `flashvar` or via `webservices` and you can then pass that string back to the server when communicating via Flash.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to just share the current/logged-in user info (basically, username and id) via `FlashVars` variables. Then related user functionality will be conditioned inside flash based on those variables.

This makes things simpler when it comes to controlling user actions (sign-in / out, profile links...) and at the same time not exposing any (harmful) data to Flash.

Comment: Yes, but isn't it then too easy to open up source code and try different combinations of id/user?