# Passing $_SESSION variable values between PHP or using $GLOBALS to retrieve stored variable

Tags: php, facebook

I am desperately in need for help to resolve this issue - stucked for 2 days trying to google for a solution!

Basically, i am developing a facebook flash application. I have a fbmain.php and index.php which will check if user is signed into facebook. If so, then it will load the .swf file which is my flash game. I am using `$fbme[id]` to retrieve the id of the facebook user so that i could use it retrieve the player's information from the database to initialize the game - so called load from previous saved game progess.

For the save game to work, my idea is to store the facebook user's id, "$fbme[id]" as a `$_SESSION` variable or `$GLOBALS` variable, so that when the .swf game loads, it will in turn load "initialize-playerstats.php" which will load player's information from the database. the "initialize-playerstats.php" is suppose to retrieve the stored variable, either `$_SESSION`or `$GLOBALS` and matches the id with the database and return results accordingly. but somehow, the variables dosen't seem to be retrieved and hence could not load any data from the database.

In my fbmain.php:

```
<?php

$fbconfig['appid'] = "XXX";
$fbconfig['api'] = "XXX";
$fbconfig['secret'] = "XXX";

try {
    include_once "facebook.php";
} catch (Exception $o) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($o);
    echo '</pre>';
}
// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => $fbconfig['appid'],
            'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
            'cookie' => true,
        ));

$session = $facebook->getSession();
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
                array(
                    'canvas' => 1,
                    'fbconnect' => 0,
                    'req_perms' => 'email,publish_stream,status_update,user_birthday, user_location,user_work_history'
                )
);

$fbme = null;
if (!$session) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    exit;
} else {
    try {
        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        $fbme = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
        exit;
    }
}

// Session based graph API call.
if ($session) {
    try {
        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        $fbme = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        d($e);
    }
}

function d($d) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($d);
    echo '</pre>';
}

?>
```

And in my index.php: (codes summarized to make reading neater)

```
<?php
//session_start();
include_once "fbmain.php";
$config['baseurl'] = "http://www.xxx.com/xxx/development/index.php";


//method 1, tried to use session variable.. not working.
$_SESSION['fbId'];

//method 2, tried using $GLOBALS..not working
$GLOBALS['fbId']= $fbme[id];

//method 3, tried using this method got somewhere while googling
$GLOBALS['fbId'];
// the defined constant used to reference the global var
define(_SYSTEM_, 'fbId');

class Foo {

    // a method where you'd liked to access the global var
    public function bar() {
        print_r($this->{_SYSTEM_});
    }

    // the magic happens here using php5 overloading
    public function __get($d) {
        return $GLOBALS[$d];
    }

}
            //tried either of this method one at a time
            $_SESSION['fbId'] = $fbme[id];

            $GLOBALS['fbId'] = $fbme[id];
```

In initialize-playerstats.php:

```
<?php

require_once('docs/php/database.php');
include('docs/php/dbinfo.inc.php');

//tried method 1 to retrieve..failed
$fbId = $_SESSION['fbId'];
//tried method 2..failed
$fbId = $GLOBALS['fbId'];

//tried method 3..failed
$foo = new Foo();
$fbId = $foo->bar();

// create new instance of mysqli class and connect to database
$db = new Database($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM player WHERE fbId= $fbId";
$result = $db->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $pWood = $row['wood'];
    $pWater = $row['water'];
    $pFood = $row['food'];
    $pLevel = $row['level'];
    $pExp = $row['exp'];
    $cPopulation = $row['cPopulation'];
    $mPopulation = $row['mPopulation'];

    echo "playerStats=$pWood/$pWater/$pFood/$pLevel/$pExp/$cPopulation/$mPopulation";
}
$db->close();
?>
```

Anyone please help me out..i will really appreciate it.. anyway to allow variables to be passed between php will help a great deal. somehow using `$_SESSION['']` or `$GLOBALS` is not working.. thanks in advance!

Comment: Is facebook.php where you are calling `session_start()`? We might need to see that as well.

Comment: If you are calling the PHP file from within Flash, that's probably your problem right there - Flash doesn't necessarily continue a PHP session. You'd need to add the session ID manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transfer PHP session to flash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504651/transfer-php-session-to-flash)

Comment: Hi Pekka,
The index.php will call the flash. The flash then calls then itialize-playerstats.php.. Does it still means that there may be a problem that session maybe discontinued?

Hi Dave Child, i tried including session_start() in facebook.php and fbmain.php.. still dosent work.. could it be register_global is set to off?

Comment: Hi Pekka, could you email me at desmond.ho.2008@smu.edu.sg? ive previously sent you an email regarding your suggested solution but not sure if you've seen it.. thanks! @Pekka

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but there is no relevant answer anywhere to this that I could find on google, so spent some time scratching my head until I realised quite how stupid I was being.

Short answer: You are not passing the session id to the next page.

Long answer: If the user browser has cookies disabled your PHP session will not be passed from page to page automatically, pretty standard stuff but for some reason (myself included) we think that as we're programming in Facebook we don't need to worry about the simpler core principles underlying any decently coded PHP site.

Always pass your session to the next page in a facebook app, no matter what. Once you start a session; SID is defined as a constant for your use immediately.

try this if you want to see what SID contains:

```
print_r(SID);
```

All you need do is append the SID to your href

```
$link = "../index.php?" . SID;
```

When you start a session on the next page, your script will now pick up the Session from the SID via a $_REQUEST as it would have if cookies were enabled. The original script would now work for index.php

```
session_start();
include_once "fbmain.php";
$config['baseurl'] = "http://www.xxx.com/xxx/development/index.php";


//method 1, tried to use session variable.. IS working.
$_SESSION['fbId'];
```

This goes for any multi page Facebook app. I'm sure there are other ways such as checking the browser for cookies though this will take a page refresh to detect if you do it with PHP once youve set your test cookie.

If you want to get real time info on Cookies then you will need to work with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

i actually have a similar problem, it took me TWO days to realize that as soon as my user is redirected to my apps url in facebook it erase all variables and start counting from there. I mean, you need to set an

```
if(!isset(yoursessionvariable)){

     $yoursessionvariable = $_GET['whatever']

}
```

...in order not to lose the variable you were passing to your script (when the redirection is done your variable is going to be set to nothing

This is ofcourse in a case where you are sending a variable thorugh GET (your url) before going to the app in facebook.

hope it helps sand save time!!

Answer (score -1):

$GLOBALS is not the way to go at all. Get rid of this approach from your code and stuck with sessions. Then debug it.
At least I see no session start in your [long and messy] fbmain.php

Why not to test sessions in much shorter code, testing code?